# Solve KKT system for Quadratic Constrained Quadratic Program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker, qcqp

I'm having trouble solving one of the possible cases that arise when solving the KKT conditions of the following problem:

We have the following optimization problem in $ \mathrm x \in \mathbb R^n$, with $\mathrm Q$ being an $n\times n$ positive definite matrix, $\mathrm p \in \mathbb R^n$,$\mathrm b \in \mathbb R^n$ and $\mathrm c \in \mathbb R$
.

$$\begin{array}{ll} 
    \text{minimize} &  \mathrm x^{\top} \mathrm Q \mathrm x + 2 \mathrm p^{\top} \mathrm x \\
    \text{subject to} &  \mathrm x^{\top} \mathrm Q \mathrm x + 2 \mathrm b^{\top}\mathrm x \leq \mathrm c
\end{array}$$

Assigning multiplier $\mu \in \mathbb R$ to the constraint, I get the following KKT system:

$$
\nabla f(x) + \mu \nabla g(x) = 0 \iff 2 \mathrm Q \mathrm x + 2 \mathrm p + \mu \mathrm Q \mathrm x + 2 \mu \mathrm b = 0
$$
$$
\mathrm x^{\top} \mathrm Q \mathrm x + 2 \mathrm b^{\top} \mathrm x  \leq \mathrm c
$$
$$
\mu \geq 0
$$
$$
\mu(\mathrm x^{\top} \mathrm Q \mathrm x + 2 \mathrm b^{\top}\mathrm x - \mathrm c) = 0
$$

I have to consider 2 different cases: either $\mu = 0$ or $\mathrm x^{\top} \mathrm Q \mathrm x + 2 \mathrm b^{\top} \mathrm x - \mathrm c = 0$.

The first one is rather easy. If $\mu = 0$ then the first equation is reduced to

$$
\nabla f(x) = 0 \iff 2 \mathrm Q \mathrm x + 2 \mathrm p  = 0 \iff \mathrm x = - \mathrm Q^{-1} \mathrm p
$$

Plugging $\mathrm x $ in the second equation gives us the condition we have to check in order to validate this minimizer.
$$
 (- \mathrm Q^{-1} \mathrm p)^{\top} \mathrm Q(- \mathrm Q^{-1} \mathrm p) + 2 \mathrm b^{\top}  (- \mathrm Q^{-1} \mathrm p) \leq \mathrm c
$$

which, after manipulation and completing the square can be written as

$$
   \frac{(\mathrm p - \mathrm b )^{\top}}{\sqrt{c + \mathrm b^{\top} \mathrm Q \mathrm b  }} \mathrm Q^{-1}  \frac{(\mathrm p - \mathrm b )}{\sqrt{c + \mathrm b^{\top} \mathrm Q \mathrm b  }} \leq 1
$$

This means that when this condition is met, we can plug $x = - \mathrm Q^{-1} \mathrm p$ into the objective function to get the respective **minimum**. That is, $- \mathrm p^{\top}\mathrm Q^{-1} \mathrm p$.

My difficulty is the case when $\mathrm x^{\top} \mathrm Q \mathrm x + 2 \mathrm b^{\top} \mathrm x - \mathrm c = 0$. If I follow the same reasoning I get

$$
\mathrm x = \mathrm Q^{-1} (\frac{-2 \mathrm p - 2 \mu \mathrm b}{2 + \mu})
$$
But since $\mathrm x$ depends on $\mu$ I can't advance.

Comment: In this last case, the solution should be on the plane $2(p^T-b^T)\cdot x + c=0$

Comment: You can reduce your QCQP to an SDP. Take a look at [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/285881/91764).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, I'm trying to get the analytical solution using the KKT conditions.